# BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, objectid

Need some help here.
Tried almost everything that I found at the internet, but didn't works.

So, this is my code:

```
    const id = req.params.id.trim(); 
    Blog.findById(id)
        .then((result) => {
            res.render("details", { blog: result, title: "Blog Details" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

it's happens when I'm trying to create a new blog.

**this is my error :**

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "blogs" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Blog"
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4546:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4645:15)
    at blog_details (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/controllers/blogController.js:19:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"blogs"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'blogs',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new BSONTypeError (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/bson/lib/error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:65:23)
      at castObjectId (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:245:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1135:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1567:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1557:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1534:20)
      at cast (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:336:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (/Users/xxx/blogMongoDB/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4969:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Comment: If you console.log `req.params.id` what value are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Your request parameter `must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`
Check the `_id` in your request params. It must be a 24 hex number such as this: `61d634706a98a61edd42bf45`

This may solve your problem. It would be great if someone could provide more info about this subject.

The question is: What if the client searches for an `_id` that doesn't have a length of 24? Why is Mongoose throwing an error instead of just returning something like "id not found"?

Comment: Yes. The last point hits home with many of us. I use express-validation(Joi) to handle this and throw a 400.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was strangely running into this issue because the mongo _id needed to be a length of 24

Answer (score 1):

Convert the type of id from string to mongoose objectID(default for _id).

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

`mongodb _id` is an `ObjectID` therefore the mongoose need to look-up the Object and not the string.

nice solution: `const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id.trim());`

Answer (score 1):

Your handler `app.get('/blogs/create')` need to go ABOVE your handler `app.post('/blogs/:id')`.

Answer (score 0):

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "blogs" ==> this means that the actual value of "const id = req.params.id.trim()" is the string "blogs" and this "blogs" is not a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters that Blog.findById(id) is expecting.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids

try to check the value of the id then make sure you're sending the correct value from the front-end

Answer (score 0):

Convert `id` to `ObjectId`:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
const convertedId = ObjectId(id)
```

If conversion is not successful due to invalid `id`, then you can catch error:

```
try{
   //your code
}catch(e){
   if(e instance of BSONTypeError){
      //do whatever you need if this occurs
   }
}
```

Don't forget to `import { BSONTypeError } from "bson";`

Answer (score 0):

In my case..
I was adding an object when I should have added a string.

```
const id = req.params
```

this code gave me an object, so I had to select the id inside that object.

```
const id = req.params.streamId;
```

And if it still does not work, then add `.toString()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can't transform a normal string to an ObjectId, check the `param.id` before use it.

you can use `ObjectId.isValid("YOUR ID STRING")` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the type of id from string to mongoose objectID(default for _id).

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

i once had a similar problem
If you have a handler `app.get('/blogs/create')` place it ABOVE your handler `app.get('/blogs/:id')`.

This error is due to express trying to interpret `create` which is of type string in the url `blogs/*create*` as an id.

Answer (score 0):

new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.sId)

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest  delete node and mongoDB and try to install again,if you have tried all method and nothing work reinstall monogdb and node .its work form me atleast tho.make sure you backup document before deleting all.good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).